# How to access instance variable within components created dynamically by the component factory resolver

Tags: angular, web-component

I am creating a utility to dynamically show angular components as modal windows. I am using the ComponentFactoryResolver to dynamically generate these components on the dom. I am having trouble figuring out how to pass data between with the resolver. I am currently using the .instance property of the resolver, which seems to be the most popular from all of my online searches. But I cannot figure out how to access the values within the component that I am generating. Any help would be much appreciated.

I have tried using the @Input attribute with several different named variables, but that does not seem to be working.

This is where I attach the input value to the component

```
private attachConfig(config, componentRef){
    let inputs = config.inputs;
    let outputs = config.outputs;

    componentRef.instance.anyInput = input;

  }
```

Here is the component that I am creating with the resolver. And how I am currently trying to access the db.

```````````````````````
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import {ModalService } from '../../Services/modal.service';
import { Relationship } from 'src/Models/relationship'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-relationship-edit',
  templateUrl: './relationship-edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./relationship-edit.component.css']
})
export class RelationshipEditComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() data : Relationship;

  constructor(private modalService: ModalService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.data);
  }

  public close() {
    this.modalService.destroy();
  }

}

``````````````````````
I am not sure how to access the data that was passed in the instance variable.
```````````````````````

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz about this issue. Also @Input is not needed. You can access any public member of your class like this: (<RelationshipEditComponent>compRef.instance).data = data;